# How many admorim died in the Holocaust?

Tags: chassidic-rebbe, holocaust-shoah

How many admorim died in the Holocaust?

Comment: I'd imagine there are historians out there who track how many Hassidic grand rabbis there were in Eastern Europe ... hm ... I'm sure a lot of them were far lesser-known.

Comment: How are you defining "admor"?

Comment: Not sure this is on topic

Answer (score 7):

There's a [book](https://www.yadvashem.org/he/education/educational-materials/books/rebbes-perished.html) (*in Hebrew*) dedicated to this topic (אדמו"רים שניספו בשואה - מאת מנשה אונגר).  If you have access to Otzar HaChochma, the [full book](https://tablet.otzar.org/?lang=en#/b/155590/p/1/t/1651771120042/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c) is available online here:

Plus a [wiki listing here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95_%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94) of over 120 rabbis who perished in the Holocaust (some of whom are rebbes/Admorim).

And a [small photo gallery here](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=28468) dedicated to the subject.

Another page [here](https://toratcha.com/?page_id=12) has photos and captions of rabbanim who perished in the Holocaust.  For the Admorim among them (around 30), search for those with the title **רבי** as opposed to the title **הרב**.